How to query from a table in Bigquery with a dictionary with value of list of lists
I have a bigquery table as following



idx
info




1
{'columns':['name','age'], 'data':[['Sheldon', 29], ['Raj',28]]}


2
{'columns':['name','age'], 'data':[['Leonard', 28], ['Howard',29]]}



info is a string column
I want to unnest it like the bellow



idx
name
age




1
Sheldon
29


1
Raj
28


2
Leonard
28


2
Howard
29




Consider also below solution (BigQuery) with column names also derived from data
SELECT * EXCEPT(pos) FROM (
  SELECT 
    idx, pos, TRIM(column, '"\'') AS column, TRIM(value, '[]"\'') AS value
  FROM data,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(info, '$.data')) AS entry WITH OFFSET AS pos,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(entry)) AS value WITH offset
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(info, '$.columns')) AS column WITH offset 
  USING (offset)
)
PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(value) FOR column IN ("name", "age"))

If applied to sample data in your question, output is

If you have different or more columns - you just adjust in one place FOR column IN ("name", "age"))
For example
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS idx, '{"columns":["name","age", "gender"],"data":[["Sheldon",29,"male"],["Raj",28,"female"]]}' AS info UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS idx, '{"columns":["name","age", "gender"],"data":[["Leonarda",28,"female"],["Howard",29,"male"]]}' AS info
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(pos) FROM (
  SELECT 
    idx, pos, TRIM(column, '"\'') AS column, TRIM(value, '[]"\'') AS value
  FROM data,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(info, '$.data')) AS entry WITH OFFSET AS pos,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(entry)) AS value WITH offset
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(info, '$.columns')) AS column WITH offset 
  USING (offset)
)
PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(value) FOR column IN ("name", "age", "gender"))

gives you below output


This query does exactly what you are looking for:
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS idx, '{"columns":["name","age"],"data":[["Sheldon",29],["Raj",28]]}' AS info
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS idx, '{"columns":["name","age"],"data":[["Leonard",28],["Howard",29]]}' AS info
)

SELECT 
  idx, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(entry, '$[0]') AS name,
  CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(entry, '$[1]') AS INT64) AS age
FROM data,
UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(info, '$.data')) AS entry


I'd suggest that you go through the BigQuery official documentation about JSON functions
